# Can tuples only be unpacked at variable declarations?

Tags: scala

Why is

```
var a,b,c = (0,0,0)
```

allowed but not:

```
var a,b,c = (0,0,0)
(a,b,c) = (0,0,0)   <<< fails to compile
a,b,c = (0,0,0)    <<< fails to compile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [the intupolator.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-language/E5Ed4cSadXg/uxavy99YA8YJ)

```
  var a, b, c = 0
  def pairing: Product = (11, 12)

  *(a, b) = pairing
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean

```
var (a,b,c) = (0,0,0)
```

since what you wrote is multiple assignment, not pattern matching.

And the reason is just stylistic.  Scala favors working with immutable values but allows you to use mutable ones.  Scala is--not only here--pretty short on handy features to help you work with mutable values.

That you can initialize vars with a pattern match should be considered a blessing in that context!

Answer (score 1):

`(0,0,0)` is a `Tuple3`

```
scala> var a,b,c = (0,0,0)
a: (Int, Int, Int) = (0,0,0)
b: (Int, Int, Int) = (0,0,0)
c: (Int, Int, Int) = (0,0,0)
```

Each variable `a`, `b`, `c` is affected with the tuple

On contrary, when you do

```
scala> var (a,b,c) = (0,0,0)
a: Int = 0
b: Int = 0
c: Int = 0
```

`a`, `b`, `c` are simple `Int`, Scala uses the extractor method of the `Tuple3` for deconstructing the object.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can introduce a binding without using `val` or `var` is in a for comprehension or in pattern matching. The form you were going for, as Rex showed, is `val (a, b, c) = (0, 1, 2)`. This is known as "irrefutable pattern matching," since there's no accommodation for a mis-tmatch between the right-hand side and the pattern after `val`. And it is not limited to `TupleN`. E.g.:

```
case class CC1(i: Int, d: Double, s: String)

val CC1(j, e, t) = CC1(1, 2.0, "three")
j: Int = 1
e: Double = 2.0
t: String = three
```