# Initialize several objects at once

Tags: scala

I have a Type called Mark, and a 4 variables initialized to null. They are declared as:

```
var markA: Mark = _
var markB: Mark = _
var markC: Mark = _
var markD: Mark = _
```

Currently, I am initializing them in a method:

```
markA = new Mark()
markB = new Mark()
markC = new Mark()
markD = new Mark()
```

What's the right way to initialize them all without writing "= new Mark()" repeatedly?  I was trying to do something like the following inside a method

```
List(markA,markB,marcC,mardD).foreach(_ = new Mark())
```

But the compiler warns me that this is a reassignment to a val, which makes sense. How can I initialize them all at once?

Comment: Similar question, where I cheated with a macro. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601429/can-tuples-only-be-unpacked-at-variable-declarations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var markA, markB, markC, MarkD = new Mark()
```

Will assign to each one a new instance of Mark.
E.g. with mutable.Map

```
scala> var a,b,c = collection.mutable.Map("a"->1)
a: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1)
b: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1)
c: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1)

scala> a += ("b"->1)
res1: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(b -> 1, a -> 1)

scala> a
res2: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(b -> 1, a -> 1)

scala> b
res3: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1)

scala> c
res4: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1)
```

Comment: Hmm, that works if I want to initialize it where I declare it, but it doesn't seem to work when I initialize post declaration. "markA, markB, markC, MarkD = new Mark()"  causes my IDE to identify the first three variables as a useless expression. Is there a way to do something almost the same but after declaring?

Answer (score 1):

If it is acceptable for storing the variables in a List/Array, you can seperate declaration and initialization into 2 stages:

declare:

```
var marks = Array.fill[Mark](4)(null)
```

initialize:

```
marks = marks map (x => new Mark)
```

Comment: This is much better! Thanks! Updated according to your comments:)